# C++ - Behavior of function template specialization with rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, rvalue-reference, enable-if

I'm trying to implement a conditional pointer dereferencing function. The basic idea is as follows:

```
return is_pointer(arg) ? *arg : arg
```

In order to limit the number of necessary specialization, I'm attempting to use rvalue references for the case where `arg` is not a pointer. Here is my current implementation (the `std::cout` are there solely for debugging purpose):

```
template< typename T >
inline typename std::enable_if< std::is_pointer< T >::value == false, T >::type deref(T&& t)
{
    std::cout << std::is_pointer< T >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid (T).name() << std::endl;
    return t;
}

template< typename T >
inline typename std::enable_if< std::is_pointer< T >::value == true, typename std::remove_pointer< T >::type& >::type deref(T t)
{
    std::cout << std::is_pointer< T >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid (T).name() << std::endl;
    return *t;
}
```

Now, I get a rather strange behavior under GCC 4.6. The first overload is used for both the non-pointer types and the pointer types. Obviously, when using a pointer type, it conflicts with the second overload. If I comment out the second one and call the following using the first one...

```
int q;
int *p = &q;
deref(p);
```

... the corresponding console output is:

```
0
Pi
```

How is it possible that a non-pointer type (according to `std::is_pointer`) is also a pointer type (according to `typeid`) in the same context? The conflict arises between both overloads due to `std::is_pointer` wrongly reporting `p` as a non-pointer type. Also, when I replace the r-value reference with a standard reference in the first overload:

```
inline typename std::enable_if< std::is_pointer< T >::value == false, T >::type deref(T& t)
```

It doesn't conflict with the second overload anymore... I simply don't get what's going on. By the way, using the second overload yields (as would be expected):

```
1
Pi
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand

```
template <T>
void foo(T&&)
```

means that if `T` is a lvalue, it will be deduced as a reference (`T = int*&` in your case) and after reference collapsing of `int*&&&` yields a regular lvalue reference `int*&`. If it wasn't like that, this syntax would capture anything as a rvalue reference. Whereas the point is to bind lvalues to lvalue references and rvalues to rvalue references.

And `is_pointer<int*&>` is not true. Hence you might try applying `remove_reference<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanations. It indeed compiles when I use the remove_reference in the enable_if condition. I don't exactly get what you mean by:

Answer (score 2):

In your first overload T is being deduced as int*&.  Try in your first overload to use `remove_reference<T>::type` in your enable_if-testing and output.